# How to detect which screen is in front in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

After moving from one screen to another how to detect if previous screen in front or not? I just wanted to update 2nd screen but it was updating 1st screen too.

Comment: What does update mean? Use a real time database

Comment: Yes I can do that but the thing is I am fetching data from REST API and I am trying use same Action and Reducer to fetch data for both of the screens. In this way I just want that when I go to next screen it just dont update the state of previous screen.

Comment: You can use the RefreshControl component in react native or disable the back button and force navigation for the user with `this.props.navigation.navigate()`

Comment: Okay thanks I'll try that